# Finding specific AWS Lambda invocation logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Suppose I have a lambda function, which processes newly created objects in S3. S3 event is printed to the console.
I see that some of the objects are not processed and I want to check the logs for the related invocation of lambda. However, there are thousands of invocations of the function. Is there any way to find the specific one? I found no ability to search from log group.
What is the AWS best practice for this?

Comment: Take a look at CloudWatch Logs Insights. If you write your logs in a specific format then it's easy to find them, filter on them, visualize them etc. later with Insights.

Comment: @jarmod wow, I haven't heard about this before. Thanks! It is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to get better visibility into your Lambda function logs:

1: You can stream your Amazon CloudWatch logs to Amazon ElasticSearch Service and conveniently search and filter the logs using Kibana.

- [Streaming CloudWatch Logs Data to Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html)
- [Configure CloudWatch Logs and Kibana](https://eksworkshop.com/intermediate/230_logging/configurecwl/)

2: You can directly analyze log data with CloudWatch Logs Insights.

- [Analyzing Log Data with CloudWatch Logs Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html)